# Apache SSL setup failure

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, debian

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www
ServerName www.mattsplacein.space
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/myurl_space.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/CA Bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Options -Indexes    
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Options -Indexes
        </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /media/usbstick/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can some one help me? I am trying to enable my SSL certificate. So that i can run it though my site. However it failing to start when i reboot apache. Does anyone have any ideas of how i can fix it?
This is the error log it think i got
"apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
"

Comment: Can you try to run `apachectl configtest` just to be sure that everything is OK with config?

Comment: It fails at SSLEngine on. It suggest i spelt it wrong

Comment: Have you enabled ssl_module for apache? `a2enmod ssl_module`